# React file input onChange not changing the picture?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webforms

I am getting a thumbnail from the user for a particular store. When the file Browse button is clicked, and an image is opened, this sets the thumbnail for the given store; however, I have also added a small x button on the top right of the thumbnail whose purpose in life is to remove this picture and to add a new one. The main problem that I am facing is when I select a thumbnail, and when I click on the x button, it removes the image, but if I choose the same drawn image, it does not add it as a thumbnail. So I have to select a different image to choose the old one.

```
import thumbnail from "../../../../Assets/thumbnail.png";
import deleteicon from "../../../../Assets/close.svg";
const thumbimage = dataType64toFile(thumbnail);
const [image, setImage] = useState(thumbimage);
const [filename, setFileName] = useState("Upload Image");
const [picture, setPicture] = useState(thumbnail);
const [close, setClose] = useState(false);




{close && (
          <img
            src={deleteicon}
            alt="Delete Thumbnail"
            className="thumbnail-close"
            onClick={() => {
              setImage(thumbimage);
              setPicture(thumbnail);
              setFileName("Upload Image");
              setClose(false);
            }}
          />
        )}


<Form.File
          type="file"
          label={filename}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setImage(e.target.files[0]);
            setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
            setPicture(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
            setClose(true);
          }}
          custom
        />
```

Comment: can you add the code to the playground? I had the same UI to build recently. Why did you setPicture(thumbnail) and setImage(thumbimage) on close?

Comment: @AshwinChandran setImage(thumbimage) and setPicture(thumbnail) are used for the default thumbnail if the user does not select an image.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently created the same gallery of images, but my approach involved a custom hook file outside my component, i.e. I just put all my useStates and handler function outside and imported it from there.

- first a tweak, don't use `const [close, setClose] = useState(false);` instead check using `image`.
- set your file and image as null as and when you click delete icon
- regarding thumbnail and other don't set em! instead place the icon in the container and when an image is selected let it cover it!